# SUMX with 2 Filters Q

Tags: filter, powerbi, powerquery

I have the following code, which sums up all my fees for my clients.

**Code Snippert:**

```
SumAmtVar = 
SUMX (
    FILTER ( _billings, _billings[_tsg_clientid_value] = accounts[accountid] ),
    __billings[Amount]
)
```

What I need is an additional filter that filters my transaction dates for the current month or a hard coded date range.  What would the second filter look like?  Any help or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can put conditions together using the `AND()` function or more simply using `&&`.

For example,

```
SUMX(
    FILTER( Table1, <Condition 1> && <Condition 2> && <Condition 3> ),
    <Expression>
)
```